# What does 'Unk:' mean in 'Stored' column of `unzip -v` output?

Tags: zip, archiving, decryption, unzip

Running `unzip -v archive1.zip`, where `archive1.zip` is an encrypted archive, I get the following output:

```
Archive:  archive1.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2019-11-16 23:24 00000000  archive1/
114313805  Unk:099109732086   4% 2019-11-16 22:44 1ef985bf  archive1/1.mp4
105319429  Unk:099101084312   4% 2019-11-16 22:44 eebbbde7  archive1/2.mp4
107103758  Unk:099102799257   4% 2019-11-16 22:45 dee65163  archive1/3.mp4
85603336  Unk:09982215648   4% 2019-11-16 21:56 84f52e69  archive1/4.mp4
84173403  Unk:09981781201   3% 2019-11-16 21:57 4b98d940  archive1/5.mp4
99122800  Unk:09996280568   3% 2019-11-16 21:58 3845f6eb  archive1/6.mp4
140263355  Unk:099136233079   3% 2019-11-16 22:00 31aa4007  archive1/7.mp4
136174590  Unk:099130823455   4% 2019-11-16 22:00 17591821  archive1/8.mp4
78035332  Unk:09974880674   4% 2019-11-16 22:01 774c2a37  archive1/9.mp4
65603509  Unk:09963086668   4% 2019-11-16 22:02 6440490e  archive1/10.mp4
80659649  Unk:09977446195   4% 2019-11-16 22:03 fa00ff0e  archive1/11.mp4
104755598  Unk:099101751952   3% 2019-11-16 22:03 56d38761  archive1/12.mp4
76602784  Unk:09973535589   4% 2019-11-16 22:04 86036941  archive1/13.mp4
77177317  Unk:09974087488   4% 2019-11-16 22:05 67dc781b  archive1/14.mp4
94371918  Unk:09994326744   0% 2019-11-16 22:06 451ad487  archive1/15.mp4
64995734  Unk:09962474109   4% 2019-11-16 22:06 cf39a151  archive1/16.mp4
```

I'm going to try to crack it using [bkcrack](https://github.com/kimci86/bkcrack) (I have some videos that are possibly recorded from the same camera, so I can use the video container header as known bytes). However, for such an approach I need to know what do `Unk:09`... values mean and, speaking more broadly, what software was used to create the archive (multiple options are also OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNK` just means your file is AES encrypted.

This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674080/how-to-open-winzip-password-protected-archive

> If it turns out you do have AES encryption and you need a python way to read the file, the standard zipfile approach will not work. As things stand zipfile only supports weak encryption.
> For other python ways to read AES-encrypted Zip files see [Python unzip AES-128 encrypted file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553150/python-unzip-aes-128-encrypted-file)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Can I somehow determine whether the files are deflated or not?

Comment: Given `cmpr` is > 0% in some cases, I would say they're not entirely deflated.

Comment: Can you please mark it as the correct answer, if you are satisfied?